# How to make language chooser as country flags in Django-cms?

Tags: css, django-cms

Well, question is in title. Is it possible at all?
I can use css to make links looks like flags, it's easy, but there is a text also (English, French, Deutsch, etc.)
Well, I will be grateful fo any kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I made that (suddenly somebody find is useful). You must change the file language_chooser.html as follows:

```
{% load cms_tags i18n %}
{% for language in languages %}
<a href="{% page_language_url language.0 %}"{% ifequal lang language.0 %} class="current"{% endifequal %}><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}[path to your flags images]{{ language.0 }}.gif" /></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The template path is "menu/language_chooser.html" but you can override it with {% language_chooser "path-to-my-apps/language_chooser.html" %}

Answer (score 19):

Using flags to represent languages is generally not a very good idea. As the W3C [puts it](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/#ri20040808.173208643):

> **Do not use flag icons to indicate languages.**
>
> Flags represent countries, not languages. Numerous countries use the same language as another country, and numerous countries have more than one official language. Flags don't map onto these permutations.

For more in-depth discussion, see e.g. http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/flags.html.

Comment: It is reasonable notice, but so happened that it was not my idea and I need flags. In any case, thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Gennadich, don't take it personally, some responses are for other people who find your question.